# How can I draw only certain values in iOS charts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using [swift charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and want to know if it is possible to set which values are drawn on a line chart.

In my chart, I skip the first and last values because they will be cut off the screen. Is this possible?

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use your own value formatter to hide some values of data entries.

E.g. define value formatter class:

```
class MyValueFormatter: IValueFormatter {
    var hiddenEntries: [ChartDataEntry?] = []

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
        return hiddenEntries.contains(entry) ? "" : "\(value)"
    }
}
```

and then use this formatter in your code to hide first and last values:

```
let myValueFormatter = MyValueFormatter()
myValueFormatter.hiddenEntries = [dataSet.entryForIndex(0), dataSet.entryForIndex(dataSet.entryCount-1)]
dataSet.valueFormatter = myValueFormatter
```